# How to debug custom workflow activity

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to debug custom workflow activity on Dynamics CRM 2013 Online by following this guide:
[first](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/rdt/2013/03/08/debugging-workflow-custom-activities-with-plugin-registration-tool/)
[second](http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-to-debug-crm-2011-online-plugin.html)

I'm stuck in starting the debugging from profiler since I cannot download or copy/paste the serialized profile. I can dig it from the page source but when I try to start execution i get following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>CallStack</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions)
   at PluginProfiler.Library.WorkflowAppDomainProxy.ExecuteCore(Stopwatch watch, ProfilerExecutionReport report, Object instance, Object executionParameter)
   at PluginProfiler.Library.AppDomainProxy.Execute(ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration, ProfilerExecutionReport report)</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-02-21T10:23:47.8284082Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

There is a popup error window in the second link. How can I get that? From there it would be possible to download the log file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Couple things you could check: do you have the latest CRM SDK, with the latest registration tool, and are all the references correct in your custom activity code ? The error is saying you're missing `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.dll (version 6)` which is part of the CRM SDK itself. Another possible meaning of the error is that you're attempting to invoke external assemblies (forbidden in CRM Online)

Comment: I do have the latest CRM SDK since I specially installed it because of this case. My custom workflow activity uses that library and it is added as a reference and visual studio don't give any errors about it. That library is also in the same directory as my assembly which I specified in Plugin Registration Tool.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I am having the same issue. No prompt to download error log and when I get the error message from the system job detail section, I get this same popup in the profiler. Difference is, mine is on premise and it is a plug in. 
Have you got the answer for your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find a way. What i ended up doing was that i created a text field and manually logged all information to that field during development.

Comment: For loging, use trace and write it to notes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the list of items.

- Check the SDK version and your CRM version.
- Check the dll version you are using in your project and your CRM version.
- You use below line of code to trace messages.

  ITracingService tracingService = 
  executionContext.GetExtension();
  tracingService.Trace("In Execute!");

Enable trace logging
To enable trace logging in an organization that supports this feature, in the web application navigate to Settings > Administration > System Settings. In the Customization tab, locate the drop-down menu labeled Enable logging to plug-in trace log and select one of the available options.

- Also, you can write console app and debug your workflow.
- For debugging from plugin registration go for
  https://ssharmacrm.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-to-debug-a-custom-workflow-
  activity-in-dynamics-crm/